# Как понять, какой смысл у слова «преданный»?

Tags: значения, прилагательные

- ты меня предал, теперь я преданный
- я верю тебе, я преданный

В виду этого, что означает фраза «преданный последователь»?

Comment: @enkryptor - if you want to, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47775/discussion-between-shabunc-and-enkryptor).

Answer (score 5):

Your first example is a very unnatural use of this word. You could almost always assume that "преданный" means "devoted". In those cases where "преданный" means "betrayed" it is used with instrumental case (i.e. betrayed by whom) - "преданный тобой/союзниками/итд". Or at least it is obvious from the context.

Comment: Agree, mainly from context

Comment: It is complicated... Even when the word _"преданный"_ is used with a noun in instrumental case. It does not always carry the meaning of betrayal.  Example: _"Остался по сути один сын, Костя, всей кровью преданный, свой."_ One has to rely on context.

Answer (score 4):

Когда обращаются к маленькой девочке с вопросом "подай мне ручку" - как понять, имеется ли ввиду шариковая ручка или анатомическая конечность. Из одной этой фразы - никак. Есть масса таких примеров - в том числе из-за них машинный перевод штука сложная.

Возвращаясь к вашему пример - "преданный последователь" *формально* может означать последователя, которого предали, но *по факту словоупотребления* любой русскоговорящий сразу поймёт, что речь идёт тут всё-таки о горячо преданном какому-то либо делу / идеологии человеке.

И если придётся говорить о преданном *кем-то* последователе, то так и скажу, чтобы не было лишней путаницы - "преданные руководителем партии рядовые её члены".

Answer (score 3):

There is an adjective `преданный` meaning dedicated, devoted (about a person).  There is also a participle `преданный` (past participle passive) from the verb `предать`.  `Преданный` as a participle means (one who was) betrayed.

`Преданный последователь` means either devoted follower or betrayed follower, depending on the context.  If there is no context information, the first sense (devoted follower) is the most probable.